# Routing in ASP.NET Core not working properly (I need opinions)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-5

```cs
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        //Endpoint if the application is in Developement
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                   name: "default",
                   pattern: "Workspace/{Workspace?}/{controller=Overview}/{action=Index}");
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "Account",
                    pattern: "{controller=Account}/{action=AdminLogin}");
            endpoints.MapBlazorHub(options =>
            {
                options.ApplicationMaxBufferSize = 9223372036854775807;
                options.TransportMaxBufferSize = 9223372036854775807;
            });
        });
        app.MapWhen(context => IsAuthenticated(context), HandleAuthenticationIdDev);
        app.MapWhen(context => HasWorkspace(context), HandleWorkspaceId);
    }
    else
    {
        //Endpoint if the application is in Production
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "Workspace/{Workspace?}/{controller=Overview}/{action=Index}");
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "Account",
                    pattern: "{controller=Account}/{action=Login}");
            endpoints.MapBlazorHub(options =>
            {
                options.ApplicationMaxBufferSize = 9223372036854775807;
                options.TransportMaxBufferSize = 9223372036854775807;
            });
            app.MapWhen(context => IsAuthenticated(context), HandleAuthenticationId);
            app.MapWhen(context => HasWorkspace(context), HandleWorkspaceId);
        });
    }
    
    private void HandleAuthenticationIdDev(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.Run(context =>
        {
            //AdminLogin action is auto-logging in with Administration Account
            context.Response.Redirect("Account/AdminLogin");
    
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        });
    }
    
    private void HandleAuthenticationId(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.Run(context =>
        {
            //Login action redirects you to Authentication website
            context.Response.Redirect("Account/Login");
    
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        });
    }
    
    private void HandleWorkspaceId(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.Run(context =>
        {
            //Login action redirects you to page where you choose your Workspace
            context.Response.Redirect("Workspaces");
    
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        });
    }

    //Checking if the request is like "domain.com/Workspace/Random-Guid-04932m/Home"
    private bool HasWorkspace(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        return !httpContext.Request.Query.ContainsKey("Workspace");
    }

    //Checking if the user is authenticated
    private bool IsAuthenticated(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        return !httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
    }
```

The issue with the following code is that it perfectly works then is in Development and then in production is does redirections like crazy the result is the following:

In Development:
Perfectly redirecting to /Workscpaces after auto logging in

[image: Perfectly redirecting to /Workscpaces after auto logging in]

Perfectly is routing to different controllers and actions

[image: Perfectly is routing to different controllers and actions]

And then in Production:

[image: Production error]

And the workaround (I might add more ifs but for now it does the job done):

```cs
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("")]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env;
    
        public HomeController(IWebHostEnvironment _env)
        {
            this._env = _env;
        }
    
        [Route("")]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Workspaces");
            else
            {
                if (_env.IsDevelopment())
                    return RedirectToAction("AdminLogin", "Account");
                else
                    return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything is too complicated to work properly and you don't need it.

Use attribute routing:

```
public class WorkspacesController : Controller
 
 [Route("~/Workspaces/{workspase}/Index", Name="WorkSpaces")]
public IActionResult Index(string workspace)
```

after this you can redirect like this:

```
return RedirectToRoute("Workspaces", new { workspace = ...});
```

Comment: Thank you very much Sergey for your feedback. Actually I am trying to implement some kind of self made AAD system, and having this redirections are critical in order to work. Your solution and my "workaround" is too simple for my needs. But still thank you. I even posted this issue on Github, we will see what I will get from there!